# How to make a college course for a novel topic?

Tags: teaching, independent-researcher, lecture-teaching-method

I am an amateur mathematician. (I studied in a university but have not finished the study.)
I discovered some new mathematical theories.

Now I want to make academic courses about my theories.
What I need to do to make college or university courses?

A textbook already exists (it is the book where I expressed my theories). What do we need next? Lecture notes? More exercises in the book? Video lectures? A dedicated book of exercises? Something else?
After I prepare all these materials, how to advertise them so that universities would start to teach my theories?

Which sites can I upload my lectures to?

Comment: Which courses are offered at a given university is usually up to the individual professors, at least at the graduate level. As long as you refuse to engage mathematicians in any way about what makes your theories interesting, nobody will want to teach a course in them.

Comment: Not sure why it is downvoted. Although this is a somewhat unusual question, I think it is quite interesting.

Comment: @Co3O4 I think that the reason this question is being downvoted is that the OP has asked already several questions on how to advertise his theory, and the answer is more or less always the same.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft well, publishers sometimes provide free books to instructors to encourage them to use these books in a course. I guess with enough money you could make at least some people teach whatever you want them to teach.

Answer (score 12):

Think about this for one or two second/s: Why should universities teach about your theories? Universities teach courses because their content is important for the students. 
So, you should communicate to the scientific or industrial world why your theories are important. Do they solve important problems? Do they give a better understanding of a certain area?

So what you should do is: Publish papers in good journals about your theories and why they are important. If the communitiy feels your theories are truly important, they will, sooner or later, teach them.
This might not apply if your theories are too advanced (read: it cannot be taught to students because too much theory is needed before one could study your theories). In this case, if you happen to have a website, write down your theories. If the theories are good enough, supervisors in your field will point students to your website (and your papers and books). Don't forget to add the most important thing at the beginning: what the benefit for the reader is. Good luck!

Comment: Also, I had a quick look at your homepage and think it sheds a bad light on you as a scientist. For example, I found some advice on what "girls" believer should choose and your site "Searching for a fiancee (Christian)". There you write that you seek a "non-fat" woman, "knowing university-level math" etc. This sounds very unacademic (it almost reads to me like a joke). I do not mean to offend you, but please consider removing these contents (or at least separate them from your scientific page). They will not help you but rather make you look unacademic or even unintelligent.

Comment: Indeed, I feel that anyone doing a small background check of him will find objectionable things. 
If he wants to be that open on the internet, he might want to try to keep things politcally / ethically correct. Things like asking for money donations to prevent an asteroid striking earth I'd find slightly.. objectionable.

Answer (score 6):

> Now I want to make academic courses about my theories

You cannot really talk university professors into delivering courses on a topic they are not interested in. And, usually, professors do not deliver courses on topics which are not well established or, at least, for which a certain degree of usefulness has not been foreseen. *And this regardless of the teaching material you're going to offer*.

> What I need to do to make college or university courses?

First and foremost, you have to convince the mathematical community that your new theory is (mathematically) interesting. Otherwise, why should anyone teach it? And if you want to be taken seriously, you should certainly do it through the usual venues (e.g., journal papers, conferences etc.), but, most of all, you should clearly: i) show that there is problem (not necessarily a practical one: e.g., it can be a weakness or a limitation in an existing theory); and ii) show that your theory is cool *because* it solves the problem. This process can take years.

Beware, however, that should your theory become accepted, then it might or not become the topic of a course anyway. In fact, if having a theory accepted by the mathematical community is quite probably a necessary condition to have courses on that theory, this is by no means a sufficient condition. That is, not all theories find their way into courses (simply, there's not enough room).

I invite you to reconsider your motivations and your actions in light of the paragraphs above. If having a course on one's work is certainly rewarding, you have to realize that probably no single author has courses entirely dedicated to their work.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it would be sensible to wait until you have finished your degree. You should also publish your theories. Nobody is going to teach your theories if they don't know about them, and nobody is going to teach your theories if they're uninteresting and irrelevant. Getting them published and generating a bit of excitement around them, plus also showing that they're relevant enough to do a course on it, will help you.

Also, you need to do some serious cleaning on your online persona to be honest. You should really make an effort to keep your political and religious views separate from your professional views.

Answer (score 0):

Since a textbook already exists, I think (of the possibilities you mention) the next step would be video lectures.

In the past, most new mathematics by amateurs never even got that far.  But nowadays you can do it yourself, put it on YouTube or Vimeo or similar video sharing site.